# Finding the best probability distribution given a set of probability distributions.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Consider a system whose output is a discrete random variable $X$ with probability mass function given by $p_t$. Here $t$ indicates that the distribution $p_t$of the random variable $X$ is a function of time (discrete). Suppose I have obtained a sequence (kind of a time series) of distributions corresponding to $X$, say $D= \{p_1,....,p_n\}$. How to find the best distribution $p_X$ that represents the random variable $X$ with respect to an appropriate metric?

Can someone guide me to some metric/results/frameworks in probability and statistics that address my problem?

Comment: The setup is unclear; are you saying that the distribution for $X$ is changing over time, and given its past distributions you want to predict its future ones?

Comment: Yes, exactly! I want to find the distribution which captures the previously observed distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using recurrent neural network if you have enough data. look for relative entropy or KL distance it might help.

Comment: Well, I have something like 10 to 15 instance of distributions. NN may not apply here.